# has_many :through and join table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I would like to implement properly database and associated models for my application.

I have two models: `user` and `location`. I would like them to be joined by a table due to the fact that I need to keep historic data about the association between these two entities.

Therefore, I created a join table called `user_locations` in addition to the foreign keys of `location_id` and `user_id` I have two additional fields which I need.

So far so good.

A new requirement has emerged and I need my `location` to be polymorphic.
I don't know how to set up my models properly to store to be able to have that joined table and a polymorphic association.

Here is what I came up with so far:

`user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :locations, through: :user_locations, as: :locationable, source_type: 'User'
  has_many :user_locations
end
```

`location.rb`

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :locationable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :users
end
```

`user_location.rb`

```
class UserLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location

  validates_presence_of :user
  validates_presence_of :location

end
```

Comment: It seems the only model that needs the location is User. Is that correct?

Comment: At this very moment yes. But the location will belong to other models in the future. In each case for example `user_location` i need a join table that will store some additional info

Answer (score 1):

I found a very good tutorial/article that [I think can help you here.](https://www.sihui.io/has_many-through-and-polymorphic/)

It would entail you doing something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations
  has_many :model_ones, through: :locations, source: :locationable, source_type: 'ModelOne'
  has_many :model_twos, through: :locations, source: :locationable, source_type: 'ModelTwo'
```

And:

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :locationable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Where `ModelOne` and `ModelTwo` are filled in with the models you need obviously.